# Can someone explain MaxAbsScaler in Scikit-learn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I was reading the docs for MaxAbsScaler.

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#scaling-features-to-a-range

I can't understand what exactly it does.

Here is an example:

```
>>> X_train = np.array([[ 1., -1.,  2.],
...                     [ 2.,  0.,  0.],
...                     [ 0.,  1., -1.]])
...
>>> max_abs_scaler = preprocessing.MaxAbsScaler()
>>> X_train_maxabs = max_abs_scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
>>> X_train_maxabs                # doctest +NORMALIZE_WHITESPACE^
array([[ 0.5, -1. ,  1. ],
       [ 1. ,  0. ,  0. ],
       [ 0. ,  1. , -0.5]])
>>> X_test = np.array([[ -3., -1.,  4.]])
>>> X_test_maxabs = max_abs_scaler.transform(X_test)
>>> X_test_maxabs                 
array([[-1.5, -1. ,  2. ]])
>>> max_abs_scaler.scale_         
array([2.,  1.,  2.])
```

It says that it scales in a way that the training data lies within the range [-1, 1] by dividing through the largest maximum value in each feature.

I think it works per column when it says in each feature.

A simpler explanation would be great.

Comment: your explanation is correct. Each column is a distinct feature

Comment: Thanks, but how does the function work? I tried giving different numbers to observe how they change but I couldn't detect a pattern.

Comment: It is a re-scaling based on (absolute) maximum value. Try implementing one your own and see

Comment: let me know if my answer helps

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The function **Scales each feature by its maximum absolute value.**
Feature here it's each column of the X input matrix.

---

Here you have:

```
X_train = np.array([[ 1., -1.,  2.],
                    [ 2.,  0.,  0.],
                    [ 0.,  1., -1.]])
```

and you get:

```
array([[ 0.5, -1. ,  1. ],
       [ 1. ,  0. ,  0. ],
       [ 0. ,  1. , -0.5]])
```

---

**Train set Explanation**:

The first feature in `X_train` is the first column i.e. `[1,2,0]`. The maximum absolute value is `2`. Then you divide all values of this column by `2`. So the new column becomes `[0.5,1,0]`

Similarly you do the same thing for the other 2 features/columns. 
For feature 2, the maximum absolute value is `1`. So the new column remains the same.

Finally, for the last feature you have a maximum absolute value of `2`. So the final feature becomes `[2/2 , 0/2 , -1/2] = [1, 0, -0.5]`.

---

**Test set Explanation**

Next, you define `X_test = np.array([[ -3., -1.,  4.]])`. Here you have one sample with 3 features.

**IMPORTANT**: *The scaler was trained using the training set and will use the maximum absolute values of the training set.*

So you get: `[ -3./2, -1./1,  4./2] = [-1.5, -1. ,  2. ]`

P.S: The values `2,1 and 2` that are used for the division are coming from th eestimation using the training set.

Comment: Wow so easy now.Great work. Can you tell me why would we want to use that on the data before training with SVM?

Comment: In general, using any mL model, it's a good idea to always scale the data before fitting the model. If you do not scale then feature with large range will be more affecting the model compared to the ones that have lower range of values. Consider accepting my answer

Comment: So for normalizing mostly?

Comment: any kind of scaling can be used. MinMax, Standardisation, MaxAbsolute etc

Comment: Can you help with this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58375486/check-skills-of-a-classifier-in-scikit-learn ?