# Check skills of a classifier in scikit learn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, nlp

After training a classifier, I tried passing a few sentences to check if it is going to classify it correctly.

During that testing the results are not appearing well.

I suppose some variables are not correct.

**Explanation**

**I have a dataframe called `df` that looks like this:**

```
                                              news        type
0   From: mathew <mathew@mantis.co.uk>\n Subject: ...   alt.atheism
1   From: mathew <mathew@mantis.co.uk>\n Subject: ...   alt.space
2   From: I3150101@dbstu1.rz.tu-bs.de (Benedikt Ro...   alt.tech
                                                            ...
#each row in the news column is a document
#each row in the type column is the category of that document
```

**Preprocessing:**

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn import metrics

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer( stop_words = 'english')
   
vectors = vectorizer.fit_transform(df.news)
clf =  SVC(C=10,gamma=1,kernel='rbf')

clf.fit(vectors, df.type)
vectors_test = vectorizer.transform(df_test.news)
pred = clf.predict(vectors_test)
```

**Attempt to check how some sentences are classified**

```
texts = ["The space shuttle is made in 2018", 
         "stars are shining",
         "galaxy"]
text_features = vectorizer.transform(texts)
predictions = clf.predict(text_features)
for text, predicted in zip(texts, predictions):
   print('"{}"'.format(text))
   print("  - Predicted as: '{}'".format(df.type[pred]))

   print("")
```

**The problem is that it returns this:**

```
"The space shuttle is made in 2018"
  - Predicted as: 'alt.atheism    NaN
alt.atheism    NaN
alt.atheism    NaN
alt.atheism    NaN
alt.atheism    NaN
```

What do you think?

## EDIT

Example

This is kind of how it should look like :

```
>>> docs_new = ['God is love', 'OpenGL on the GPU is fast']
>>> X_new_counts = count_vect.transform(docs_new)
>>> X_new_tfidf = tfidf_transformer.transform(X_new_counts)

>>> predicted = clf.predict(X_new_tfidf)

>>> for doc, category in zip(docs_new, predicted):
...     print('%r => %s' % (doc, twenty_train.target_names[category]))
...
'God is love' => soc.religion.christian
'OpenGL on the GPU is fast' => comp.graphics
```

Comment: How many items are in your trainingdata df?

Comment: about 700 rows.

Comment: how similar are your test phrases to your training data document? How many different categories are there?

Comment: the data are freely available here: http://qwone.com/~jason/20Newsgroups/ , the categories are many but I have used only a few to keep the processing fast.

Comment: @chefhose from the same dataset are both train and test data.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in the comments, you have around 700 samples. To test how good your classifier works, you should always split your data into training and test samples. For example 500 sample as training data and 200 to test your classifier. You should then only use your training samples for training and your test samples for testing. Test data created by hand as you did are not necessarily meaningful. sklearn comes with a handy [function](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) to separate data into test and training:

```
#separate training and test data, 20% og your data is selected as test data
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
df_train, df_test = train_test_split(df, test_size=0.2)

vectors = vectorizer.fit_transform(df_train.news)
clf =  SVC(C=10,gamma=1,kernel='rbf')
#train classifier
clf.fit(vectors, df_train.type)

#test classifier on the test set
vectors_test = vectorizer.transform(df_test.news)
pred = clf.predict(vectors_test)
#prints accuracy of your classifier
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
classification_report(df_test.type, pred)
```

This will give you a hint how good your classifier actually is. If you think it is not good enough, you should try another classifier, for example [logistic regression](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html). Or you could change your data to all lower case letters and see if this helps to augment your accuracy.

**Edit:**
You can also write your predictions back to your test_datframe:

```
df_test['Predicted'] = preds
df_test.head()
```

This will help you to see a pattern. Is acctually all predicted as alt.atheism as your example suggests?

Comment: I have already split them. If you see there is a **df_test** variable that has the test data.To be precise the test data are coming from the test data folder of that dataset. They are not made up. You haven't addressed the main part of the question which is how to check some sentences, how they are classified (lower part of the text in my question).Why does it print the weird result in my question where I test some sentences where they belong? Thanks

Comment: so how does your classifier perform on your test set?

Comment: Check the edit I made to see how it should look like.Can you help on how to do that?

 BTW the accuracy I got was slightly more than 90%.

Answer (score 0):

The data with which you train your classifier is significantly different to the phrases you test it on. As you mentioned in your comment on my first answer, you get an accuracy of more than 90%, which is pretty good. But you tought your classifier to classify mailing list items which are long documents with e-mail adresses in them.  Your phrases such as "The space shuttle is made in 2018" are pretty short and do not contain e-mail adresses. Its possible that your classifier uses those e-mail adresses to classify the documents, which explaines the good results. You can test if that is really the case if you remove the e-mail adresses from the data before training.

Comment: based on the tf-idf, it should be able to identify that a sentence that has 'space' and 'shuttle' should be part of the space category. Okay can you add to your answer what you think would be optimal approach(for example remove email addresses) and how would I check these sentences, where they belong?